# Forcing Psychopy's staircase to ignore missed responses

Tags: psychopy

we have created a MultiStair instance which works fine, but we would want to ignore trials when the participant didn't respond (and by default Psychopy counts it as incorrect, so missed responses bias the staircase result).
Is there a way to do it without remodeling the source code?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't told us which interface you're using (Builder or code).

From Builder the answer is no. Nothing is built in for that. A missed response counts as a fail (which seems appropriate). If subjects are failing to respond when they have successfully seen the stimulus then maybe you need to think about allowing more time to respond?

From code you would need to add a loop around the code that presents your stimulus, in such a way as to repeat your trial until a response is found, and only then call `addData(resp)`

Comment: Sorry, for the insufficient information. Either interface is good, so I will try the coder solution (which seems kind of obvious, now that I've read it) and see if it will do the job. Thanks!